# Understanding javascript DOM core ideas: nodeList vs HTMLElement objects

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I have been working towards understanding the DOM very thoroughly. At the moment i'm making my way trough traversing the DOM tree and i seem to be finding some inconsistencies.

- a **nodeList** is returned when i select more than 1 element
- a **HTMLElement** is returned when i select only 1 element

So the question is, why does this code return a **nodeList**, even if i select only 1 li.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AmhVk/5

Could someone explain this to me very thoroughly? Thx...

```
<ul id="jow">
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>    
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Item</a></li> 
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ieps"></div>

function simple(){

var li = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
var ul = li[0].parentNode;
var getULchild = ul.children[0];

var ieps = document.getElementById("ieps");

ieps.innerHTML += "ul will return = " + ul + "<br>";
ieps.innerHTML += "li will return = " + li + "<br><br>";        

ieps.innerHTML += "ul[0] will return: " + ul[0] + "<br>";
ieps.innerHTML += "li[0] will return: " + li[0] + "<br><br>";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction :

- a **nodeList** is returned when you call a function which may select more than 1 element
- a **HTMLElement** is returned when you call a function which can select 1 element at most

This way you don't have to test the type of the returned value at each call.

`querySelectorAll` is designed to return an undefined number of elements, so it returns a `nodeList`.

On the contrary there's generally no point in returning a nodeList when you use `getElementById` (as one element at most may have a given id), that's why it directly returns one element (or null).

Comment: So li[0].parentNode; calls a function which can select 1 element at most?

Comment: You should see `parentNode` as a property, not a function. And yes, there's at most one parent of a given element.